# How to update state in reducer

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have a problem with my reducer. I am using redux to create a login page. I have successfully logged in yet I failed to navigate to the next page. The state in my reducer is not updated. How do I solve this?

This is how I wrote my reducer:

```
import { LOGIN_SUCCESS } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE={
  isLoginSuccess:false,
}
export default function (state=INITIAL_STATE, action){
switch(action.type){
  case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
   return {
     isLoginSuccess : true
   }

  default:
    return INITIAL_STATE;
 }
}
```

This is how I wrote my action:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as helper from '../common';
import { LOGIN_SUCCESS } from './types';

export const attemptLogin = (username, password) => async dispatch => {

let param = {
    txtNomatrik: username,
    txtPwd: password,
    public_key: helper.PUBLIC_KEY,
    secret_key: helper.SECRET_KEY

}

console.log(`${helper.ROOT_API_URL}/v1/basic/ad/std/login`)
let login_res = await 
axios.post(`${helper.ROOT_API_URL}/v1/basic/ad/std/login`, param)

console.log(login_res.data);

if (login_res.data.status == 'Successful Login') {
    const { login } = login_res.data;
    await AsyncStorage.seItem('Login_token', username);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(login));
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: { isLoginSuccess : true } });

}
}
```

I want to use the isLoginSuccess in my index file to navigate login to the next page like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.isLoginSuccess){
        this.props.navigation.navigate('logged');
    }

}
```

Below is how I connect redux:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => {
return {
    isLoginSuccess: auth.isLoginSuccess
}
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(LoginScreen);
```

Below is my combineReducer file:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import news from './welcome_reducer';
import auth from './login_reducer';

export default combineReducers({
news,
auth
})
```

How do I solve this? I feel lost now, have tried a lot of ways to solve it . The Api call for login is successful but the action is not dispatched at all. I can't update the state and I can't navigate to the next page. Please help me

Comment: Can we see your `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: @Li357 I added mapStateToProps in my post :)

Comment: @gdphy plase add ur combinereducers  statement as well

Comment: I added what it in my latest edit, but i dont think the problem comes from there. It just that the isLoginSuccess value not updated into true when the action being dispatched

Comment: Can anybody help me with this matter?